# I am trying to add the decade one Date picker But I am not able to get what I expected

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, calendar, client-side-scripting

I want to get 10 years..
Than i click on years and and than select a month.After selecting a month.I need to select the date and all the combination will be shown to my input type text box i have a tutorial but its doesnt seems to working.i dont know where I am doing mistake...

Tutorial Link as Follows::

http://jsfiddle.net/sperske/RkBpX/

Am I missing with any file Refrence. Please Guys Let me know.

I have made a Reference of these files:

```
 <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
    <link href="../css3menu1/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/Datepicker.js"></script>
    <link href="../Styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
```

Comment: <link href="../css3menu1/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/Datepicker.js"></script> 
returns 403 ERROR instead of file

Comment: Don't load jquery.js twice. The second version will wipe out the datepicker plugin.

Comment: Check out this link I have added those file content in js and css of fiddle.
Now that datepicker is working.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RkBpX/55/